# Git tag in Visual Studio 2015 isn't visible on GitHub web site

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I have just created a tag using Visual Studio 2015 for a GitHub project I cloned locally. I executed commit and sync.

I'm able to see the tag in the history inside Visual Studio 2015 but not on GitHub web site. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you pushed your tag?

```
$ git tag foo
$ git push origin foo
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Shine: actually that was meant as an answer, although formulated with a question mark. It's the only likely cause I can think of and it's also what 99% of newbies stumble upon when first encountering tags in git.

Comment: if 99% of newbies stumble upon this, this should be marked as duplicate then

Comment: @Shine Quite possibly indeed, but I can't find a similar question and it doesn't seem right to me to mark it as a duplicate of a *different question with the same probable cause*, if you get my gist :-) 
I must say that OP isn't giving us *a lot* to work with here anyway.

Comment: I forgot to execute "push". Thanks ;-)

Comment: @Shine: Now I want a cookie :P